# How To Check key in key pair is available or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsdictionary

i am trying to learn json with iOS.
i am trying to implement [json](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D1100661&format=json) data with `UITableView`. In my tableview row in Title and subtitle are displaying the values. I can load data in title but when try to load in subtitle, app is getting crashed because in subtitle **result** that field of json and in that many key-pair value is given. So It can't be possible to display in sub title in tableview.

My question is how can I load subtitle and if key in many key pair value is available to when click on that it gets redirected to other tableview for displaying that data.

My Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid%3D1100661&format=json"]];
    NSError *error=nil;
    id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                 NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error]; 
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        _query = [response objectForKey:@"query"];
        NSLog(@"%@",_query);
        _keyArray = [_query allKeys];   
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_keyArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;
    }

    NSString *key = [_keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSString *dictionary = [_query objectForKey:key];
    NSString *dictionary = [_query objectForKey:key];
    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dictionary;  
    return cell; 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on .. What do you want to show in cell.detailTextLabel ?

Comment: I am trying very hard to understand that what you really want to get as an output here , but I can't. Please add an image where it is mentioned that what you really want as a result of this.

Comment: If the value of subtitle is a new dictionary, do you want to expand the tableview or push to a new tableview to display the sub key-value pair.

Comment: @ArunKumar i would display cell.detailTextLabel in value of key. but in result many key pair is available so app will be crash.

Comment: Obviously it will crash. Because it is expecting a String value and you are passing a Dictionary value.

Comment: @ArunKumar yes, but how can i fix it with when select row redirect to other tableview and display other key value dynamically.

Comment: I am writing an answer for it, I hope that will help you.

Comment: @ArunKumar where is answer?

Comment: Give me sometime man. I said "I am writing it.".

Comment: you can check type of dictionary before set it to detailTextlabel. cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? dictionary : "variable is not a string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I've understood from your question and comments, here is my answer step by step...

First I have taken a `NSArray` and a `NSDictionary` properties in my  `ViewController.h` class like this.

```
{
NSArray *_allKeys;
}
 @property(nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *query;
```

Then in `ViewController.m` I have created a setter method for `query` property , where I am setting the data into `_query` and `_allKeys` like this...

```
 -(void)setQuery:(NSDictionary *)query
{
    _query = query;
    _allKeys = [_query allKeys];
    if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

Now in `UITableView` datasource method `cellForRow` , I have updated your code..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *key = _allKeys[indexPath.row];
    id value = _query[key];
    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = (NSString*)value;
    }
    else if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"More Info";
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])


       {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Multiple Entries Found";
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

// do something show array data with prototype custom cell
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

And now in `UITableView` delegate method `didSelect` , I have create a new instance for same `ViewController` (We can reuse it because , it has same UI layout), and passing the value of `_query`...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key = _allKeys[indexPath.row];
    id value = _query[key];
    if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
    {
        ViewController *nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        nextVC.query = value;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Note:** I don't want to call that `webservice` call in  `ViewController.m` ,  whenever I'm instantiating the `ViewController` instance . So I put the `webservice` code in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunch` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid%3D1100661&format=json"]];
    NSError *error=nil;
    id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                 NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
     NSDictionary*   _query = [response objectForKey:@"query"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
            vc.query = _query;
        });
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

It's up to you that where you put this code, but most preferably we should put following code in the previous `UIViewController` of your `DatashowingViewController`(Mine is `ViewController`) and pass the information to `ViewController`(like I have done), so that we can reuse the same `UIViewController` for showing same result.

I hope this answer will help you achieving your output.

Comment: app will be crash on dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
            vc.query = _query;
        });

Comment: That is to show you how to pass response data in your ViewController . Now tell me do you have your Viewcontroller as the topViewController of your UINavigationController which is the rootViewController of application window?

Comment: i can't include navigationviewcontroller and my code past in above comment.

Comment: Thanks Bro it will be work i can't json url i will load in lodametho don't in app delegate. Thanks.

Comment: In that case don’t change the place for your web service call. Just let that be written where it is written. Now make a similar NewViewcontraoller with UITableView. Write same  tableDatasource and Tabledelegate as same written as in this Viewcontroller. Copy query , _allkeys properties and setter method and paste In newviewcontroller . Now change the viewcontroller object with newviewcontroller in didSlect method.